# Arduino character array serial

Tags: c++, serial-port, char, arduino, arrays

I'm having a little bit of trouble with this bit of code here for my Arduino.

Basically, I'm trying to send in a series of characters, turn it into an character array, and use that to run the rest of the program. I'm close because I know everything is working perfectly internally, but when I boot from the serial port, the message isn't getting in.

I assume that at this point it probably is how I am constructing the array... or some oddity. It is probably just a simple error in how I put the code together, but I'm completely struck. (I was previously using a string, but because of how the Arduino works with them, it pretty much makes using them for memory purposes impossible.)

I'm using a Java program ([Ardulink](http://www.ardulink.org/what-is/)) to send the information into the program with a customized version I've edited. So simply put, the input has to be a series of characters, and I need it stored in an array.

```
void serialEvent()
{
  int arrayPostion = 0;
  int i;
  int maxArraySize = 20;
  char CharArrayInLocal[20];
  while (Serial.available() && !stringComplete)
  {
    char inChar = (char)Serial.read();
    CharArrayInLocal[arrayPostion] = inChar;
    arrayPostion++;
    if (inChar == '\n')
    {
      stringComplete = true;
    }
  }
  for (int i = 0; i<=19; i++)
  {
    CharArrayIn[i] = CharArrayInLocal[i];
  }
}
```

Comment: is this on its own thread?

Comment: You are aware that your `char CharArrayIn[20];`  is local to the `serialEvent()` function and will not be available outside that very function?

Comment: AT:jbutler483: I have no idea... but I assume so because the serial function of the arduino seems to be like setup and loop as far as I can tell. It threads it by itself.

@HannoBinder: O.o You would be correct, that is one obvious thing I clearly overlooked, give me a second to re-up the code with a transfer for loop into another global array. If that's all the problem is I'll personally buy you a bear.

Comment: @HannoBinder:I declared the variable in the local and the global, would this cause a conflict? I'll assume so and redefine the updated code.

Comment: Yes, a local variable hides the global one with the same name. The function then only sees its local version and cannot access the global one. - But you probably don't even need two arrays. Just declare one global array and write into that, unless you actually still need its contents while new data is being received (ISR?). This saves you from having to copy the local array to the global one.

Comment: The gist is may be that serialEvent() is ***line-oriented*** (not very clear in the documentation, absent in the code comments, and misleading in the example code). That is, a newline (whatever that is. ASCII 13?) is required before serialEvent is called. The canonical is *[Arduino "SerialEvent" example code doesn't work on my Arduino Nano. I can't receive serial data. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67013619/)*

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me,

```
String CharArrayInLocal[20];
String inputString = "";
boolean stringComplete = false;
int i = 0;

void serialEvent() {
  while (Serial.available()) {

    char inChar = (char)Serial.read();

    if (inChar == '\n') {

      CharArrayInLocal[i] = inputString;

      i++;
      stringComplete = true;
      inputString = "";
    }
    else {
      inputString += inChar;
    }
  }
}
```